# .bak files interfering with VS code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, visual-paradigm

I am using VS code alongside Visual Paradigm to develop my class diagrams.  It appears that the .bak files Visual Paradigm produces prevents VS code from loading my java classes if they're in the same folder.  Has anyone seen this behavior?

Comment: Can you share your project and the project structure shown in file explorer and VS Code?

Comment: So - VS Code has updated since, and now I can no longer recreate the issue. However, a folder structure like this https://github.com/dreambucket13/bakexample would cause the build to fail.  Removing the .bak and .vpp files from the folder worked.  Again, cannot reproduce now.

Comment: Add `"files.exclude": { "**/.bak": true, },` in Settings.json then see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll give that a go if I see the issue again.